# What should be my next step for learning JavaScript after W3Schools?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

*Question 1:*

I am beginning to learn JavaScript on my own. I can program in MATLAB or C, and I went through the tutorials in W3School. I am wondering what site should I visit next for a more detailed and professional level knowledge about JavaScript?

*Question 2:*

I want to build a minimal type blogging site in future, where users can open accounts, can write posts, and others can comment. Will it be very hard to pull this off by myself?

I have fundamental knowledge in HTML and CSS, and like I said, I am currently learning JavaScript. I have plans to study PHP and MySQL next. Should I continue in this manner, or should I move straight forward to WordPress?

*Question 3:*

I have zero knowledge about WordPress. Can someone build a complete forum type website using nothing else than WordPress?

Take Stack Overflow for example (only a very minimal version!), can I build site like this using WordPress, where people can open accounts, post, and comment in other's posts?

Comment: the next step is to forget everything you saw on w2fools...

Comment: You could build Stack Overflow on WordPress, but after a certain level of customisation and performance, it is a good idea to start from scratch. The WP team do some awesome work keeping WP working as well as it does, but the internals are somewhat hampered by historical technical decisions. You can learn how to build simple PHP-based form apps using [my tutorial here instead](http://ilovephp.jondh.me.uk/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

Answer 1: [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.com/) javascript track will be best suited after w3schools tutorials.

Answer 2: If you will go step by step, Nothing is hard to achieve. Start with Wireframes then Layouts then User Experience with Javascript and then Backend. It is always better to understand foundation of front end (HTML/CSS/JS) because everything usages the basic at the end, even Wordpress.

Answer 3: Yes you can make, There are many Discussion Plugins for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript design patterns, jquery, react...

https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/